# Count no.of .xlsx across all the directories and subdirectories where .tab is also exist

Tags: bash, shell

I have a directroy which consists of 'n' number of sub directories. Following is the structure:

```
RootDir -> 
SubDir1 ->  
test.xlsx
test.tab 
SubDir2 ->
test.xlsx
```

As shown above SubDir1 has both files .xlsx and .tab and SubDir2 have only .xlsx. Like this I have 'n' number of subdirectories, and willing to count only .xlsx from the folders where .tab file is also present.

I wanted to do it using shell scripting.

The present code returning me count of .xlsx files. But, it also includes the .xlsx files where .tab fiiles are not present.

```
find . -name '*.xlsx' -type f
```

Comment: Do you want to count those .xlsx files, for which .tab file exists with the same name?

Comment: @AnkushPandit yes the name is same. Just the extension changes between xlsx and tab.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work:

```
count=0
for file in `find . -name '*.xlsx' -type f`; do
  if [ -f "${file%.xlsx}"".tab" ]; then
    count=`expr $count + 1`
  fi
done
echo $count
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly refined version of Ankush Pandit's answer:

```
#!/bin/bash

count=0
while IFS= read -r -d "" f; do
    [[ -f ${f%.xlsx*}.tab ]] && (( count++ ))
done < <(find RootDir -type f -name "*.xlsx" -print0)
echo "$count"
```

- The combination of `-print0` and `read -d ""` options protects filenames
  which contain special characters such as a space character.
- The syntax `<(find ..)` is a process substitution and the output of
  `find` is fed to the `read` command in the `while` loop via the redirect.